# incorrect balance response

Tags: rpc, balances, westend, golang, free-balance

I've created test address in westend network. Topped up it using faucet. https://westend.subscan.io/account/5FpS4PkRzLmJZcwvJM6jxPU3N3481nbnTe6nzFwwQUVvu9LF?tab=transfer. In explorer I see 1WND balance, but if I try to retrive it using rpc func I receive wrong amount

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    gsrpc "github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/v4"
    config2 "github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/v4/config"
    "github.com/centrifuge/go-substrate-rpc-client/v4/types"
    "github.com/vedhavyas/go-subkey"
    "github.com/vedhavyas/go-subkey/sr25519"
)

func GetBalance(api *gsrpc.SubstrateAPI) {

    uri := balanceURI
    key, err := GetKey(uri)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    addr := PrintAddr("test balance addr", key)
    fmt.Println("addr = ", addr)
    public := key.Public()
    fmt.Println("public: ", "0x"+hex.EncodeToString(public))

    meta, err := api.RPC.State.GetMetadataLatest()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    storageKey, err := types.CreateStorageKey(
        meta, "System", "Account", public, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Retrieve the initial balance
    var accountInfo types.AccountInfo
    ok, err := api.RPC.State.GetStorageLatest(storageKey, &accountInfo)
    if err != nil || !ok {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(accountInfo)
    fmt.Println("Free balance: ", accountInfo.Data.Free)
    fmt.Println("FreeFrozen balance: ", accountInfo.Data.FreeFrozen)
    fmt.Println("MiscFrozen balance: ", accountInfo.Data.MiscFrozen)
    fmt.Println("Reserved balance: ", accountInfo.Data.Reserved)
}

func main() {
    config := config2.Default()
    config.RPCURL = WestEndUrl

    api, err := gsrpc.NewSubstrateAPI(config.RPCURL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(api)

    GetBalance(api)
}

func GetKey(uri string) (subkey.KeyPair, error) {
    scheme := sr25519.Scheme{}
    kr, err := subkey.DeriveKeyPair(scheme, uri)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return kr, nil
}

func PrintAddr(caption string, key subkey.KeyPair) string {
    addr, err := key.SS58Address(42)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(caption, addr)
    return addr
}

const WestEndUrl = "wss://westend-rpc.polkadot.io"
const balanceURI = "...//foo//42///password"
```

and the output:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go #gosetup
GOPATH=/home/andrew/go #gosetup
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o /tmp/GoLand/___go_build_sample_westend_with_faucet sample/westend_with_faucet #gosetup
/tmp/GoLand/___go_build_sample_westend_with_faucet
2022/11/07 11:39:28 Connecting to wss://westend-rpc.polkadot.io...
&{0xc0000da580 0xc0001d2090}
test balance addr 5FpS4PkRzLmJZcwvJM6jxPU3N3481nbnTe6nzFwwQUVvu9LF
addr =  5FpS4PkRzLmJZcwvJM6jxPU3N3481nbnTe6nzFwwQUVvu9LF
public:  0xa60e515cdbf7e1426e9d708bc78ee0ed7d0f4c5c04951be09e37e70ad31a487c
{0 0 1 {4294967296000000000000 0 0 0}}
Free balance:  4294967296000000000000
FreeFrozen balance:  0
MiscFrozen balance:  0
Reserved balance:  0
```

amount is 4294967296000000000000 - it's not equal to 1WND

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the library you are using is not up-to-date with the current Westend version. In particular - it decodes the response of `System.account` using the old definition of `AccountInfo`.

Notice that the printed structure contains three number values besides the nested structure with balances - `0 0 1`. However, if you will take a look at the same query in the Polkadot.js apps UI, you will see that there are actually four of them:

```
{
  nonce: 0
  consumers: 0
  providers: 1
  sufficients: 0
  data: {
    free: 1,000,000,000,000
    reserved: 0
    miscFrozen: 0
    feeFrozen: 0
  }
}
```

So the library does not know about `sufficients` field and tries to decode the bytes of `sufficients` as being nested `data` structure, thus causing corruption

Worth to mention that addition of `sufficients` is rather old change - so if the library you are using is maintained - there should be already new version available that is compatible with abovementioned changes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add more prints to check if is doing the proper calls.

I have tried the same using a basic script with [PolkadotJS](https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs)

```
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');

async function getBalance() {
  const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://westend-rpc.polkadot.io');
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });
  const chain = await api.rpc.system.chain();
  console.log(`----- Chain: ${chain} -----`);
  // The actual address that we will use
  const ADDR = '5FpS4PkRzLmJZcwvJM6jxPU3N3481nbnTe6nzFwwQUVvu9LF';
  // Retrieve the account balance & nonce via the system module
  const data = await api.query.system.account(ADDR);
  console.log(`Balance of the account ${ADDR} is: `);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

 }
```

And the result is what you should have 1WND:

```
{"nonce":0,"consumers":0,"providers":1,"sufficients":0,"data":{"free":1000000000000,"reserved":0,"miscFrozen":0,"feeFrozen":0}}
```

Trying to manually query the RPC query state_getStorage of your account:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "state_getStorage", "params":["0x26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef7b99d880ec681799c0cf30e8886371da95e0bd5326aa7e9fa72c036a33d96d381a60e515cdbf7e1426e9d708bc78ee0ed7d0f4c5c04951be09e37e70ad31a487c"]}' https://westend-rpc.polkadot.io
```

It returns you the same value too.